# How did Eduardo Salamanca manage to go to Germany?

Tags: character, better-call-saul

How did Lalo manage to pass multiple identity/security checks both ways? It seems like it shouldn't be an easy trip, given his pedigree, there should be pictures of him at any airport, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Close voters: How can OP make this question more clear? What details should OP add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the same way he was able to travel to the USA from Mexico and vice-versa — **by using a fake identity** (passports, documents, etc.). As a high-ranking member of a drug cartel, he has the resources to craft and use a fake identity to travel international borders, just like the other high-ranking cartel members in both *Better Call Saul* and *Breaking Bad*, e.g., Juan Bolsa, Gus Fring, and many others.

Also, at the time he went to Germany, the "Eduardo 'Lalo' Salamanca" identity was officially dead, purportedly assassinated by a Peruvian cartel. This makes traveling to another country using a fake identity much easier since the authorities won't be looking for a dead man.